# Added code not always visible as a change in the Reopen Votes review queue

Tags: bug, review, code-formatting, revisions-list

[Here](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/67866) is a Reopen Votes review queue item, where the author added some code to the question. However, that is not displayed in the 'Inline' and 'Side-by-side' tabs, which just show some grammar corrections:

[image]

Only when you click the 'Side-by-side Markdown' tab, the code change becomes apparent:

[image]

The [revision history page](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/posts/90905/revisions) does not have this problem, there it works fine:

[image]

Comment: I suspect it's down to the [recent changes to Highlight.js which strip out formatting from highlighted code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417860/html-formatting-inside-highlighted-code-blocks-is-no-longer-supported-how-can/417861#417861). Fortunately, as that post says, there's a plugin SE can install to work around this highlighter feature. This is why [highlighting had to be disabled in revision histories](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/411484/2157772).

Comment: Initially I thought this was related to this feature request on MSO to make it more obvious when code is edited in a part of the post that's hidden due to being offscreen and needing to scroll to it: [In the Suggested edits review queue, make it more obvious when code is edited](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/420374/1478931) – but in this case, you're right that the first 2 tabs of that review item don't indicate the code as added to the post at all... Strange indeed.